# Invalid block type: Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to get up-sell product, but getting issue with invalid block type: `Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld`  in Magento 2.

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class Upsell extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }    

}
?>
```

Here is .phtml code

```
<?php
$myBlock = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Upsell');
$currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct();

if ($currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct()) {
    $upSellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();

    if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
        echo '<h3>UpSell Products</h3>';
        foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
            echo $upSellProduct->getSku() . '<br />';        
        }
    }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context` is for adminhtml block

You should use `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context` class for frontend block

**Here is your Final Block:**

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;

class Upsell extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,   
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getProduct($productId)
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        return $product;
    }  

}
```

> Don't use **ObjectManager** directly in phtml file. Use **$block** for current template block.

**Here is your Final Phtml:**

```
<?php

$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();

if ($currentProduct) {

    $upSellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();

    if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
        echo '<h3>UpSell Products</h3>';
        foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
            $product = $block->getProduct($upSellProduct->getId());
            echo $product->getSku() . '<br />';        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prince Patel@ hi prince but when I used this , I am not getting  uppcell product , any mistake in this code

Comment: @sanjay try my updated answer

Comment: Prince Patel@can you suggest me how to get upcell product through object manager, I am getting issue width block creation, I have no option for cli so please let me know through object manager

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `ObjectManager` to get block in template like that. It is bad practices you should avoid.
Use `$block` is corresponding to your current block . In your case is `Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Upsell`

Your Constructor in Block class need to modify

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,   <== this class     
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
)
```

In your template

```
<?php /** @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Upsell $block **/

$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();

if ($currentProduct = $myBlock->getCurrentProduct()) {
   $upSellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();

   if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
       echo '<h3>UpSell Products</h3>';
       foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
         echo $upSellProduct->getSku() . '<br />';        
       }
   }


}

?>
```

Finally, remove generation by command `rm -r var/generation` in order to update code